# Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos-7

I am a newbie was trying to install gn3 on my laptop running CentOS so as I was following some instructions on the net then I realise as I was about to update my OS its now giving me this error message:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks


File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/virtualbox.repo, line: 1
'rtualbox]\n'
```